# nested dictionary built by user input

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote an executable program that displays data that is obtained from a nested dictionary of info relevant to me and is imported into the program. It works fine.

**Question:**

Is it possible to have a program that via user input creates a nested dictionary of data (relevant to the user), to a saved file?

I could have my program open that file and use its data.
my dictionary uses strings as keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly there is a way to do that in python.

first you open the save file like so:

```
with open("C:\path\to\the\save\file.pkl", "w") as save_file:
    save_file.write("This is written to the file!")
```

because of the with satatement python takes care of the closing of the file handler so you do not have to worry about this.

I am not sure what is the key and values of the dictionary are but lets assume you have a user id and his data.
Now simply read from the user and store it into a dictionary like so

```
main_dictionary = {}

id = int(input("Enter user ID> "))
data = input("Input user data> ")
main_dictionary[id] = data
```

Next you want to be able to save and load a dictionary from the file. for this use the pickle library as it is very easy to use:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:  # python 3.x
    import pickle

# stores the dictionary inside the "C:\path\to\the\save\file.pkl"
pickle.dump(main_dictionary, save_file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

To load the dictionary simply write:

```
with open('C:\path\to\the\save\file.pkl', 'rb') as save_file:
    main_dictionary= pickle.load(save_file)
```

complete program should look like this:

```
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:  # python 3.x
    import pickle

main_dictionary = {}

with open("C:\path\to\the\save\file.pkl", "rb") as save_file:
    main_dictionary= pickle.load(save_file)

id = int(input("Enter user ID> "))
data = input("Input user data> ")
main_dictionary[id] = data

with open('C:\path\to\the\save\file.pkl', 'wb') as save_file:
    pickle.dump(main_dictionary, save_file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Hope that helped

Comment: thank you,  Amit in advance. You've given me good info to work on. mention how far  I get again.

Comment: I tried the 'complete program' code above. I made a  file.pkl in the same directory,so my path was    open('file.pkl', "rb") The warning I get is 're declared main_dictionary (9th line) never used' When running ,the error is     main_dictionary = pickle.load(save_file)
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0d'. I'm royally doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the built in module, [pickle](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjsv9Wtue3pAhWvg3IEHdPFApkQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python.org%2F3%2Flibrary%2Fpickle.html&usg=AOvVaw1vtidhimcEC-N1zO7tugY3). This code will allow the user to input a name and an age, and it will keep asking for data until the user enters nothing for the name:

```
import pickle
d = {}
while True:
    name = input("Input your name: ") # Ask for name
    if not name: # Break out of the loop when the user enters nothing
        break
    age = int(input("Input your age: ")) # Ask for age
    d.update({name:age}) # Update d with given name and age

with open('dict.pickle','wb') as file: # Open a file to store dictionary
    pickle.dump(d,file) # Use pickle to dump in the dictionary
```

It will store the data in a pickle file, and when ever you want to use that data, here is what you can do:

```
import pickle

with open('dict.pickle','rb') as file:
    d = pickle.load(file) # Use pickle to load the dictionary into variable d

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```